# Redirect to url including an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to accomplish a redirect from http://www.foo.com/beta to a new directory and anchor like so;  http://www.foo.com/alpha/product/#tab-5. I tried the simple Javascript redirects

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

but without a corresponding page on the server I receive a 404. After doing some research I see that you can add a hash via .hash to the url with;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(window.location.hash == ''){ 
    window.location.hash="tab-6";
  }
</script>
```

This gives me the end result of http://www.foo.com/beta#tab-6 which is in the right direction. Is this the start of the right approach and is it feasible to redirect to a completely new directory to an anchor within the page? Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you've identified the problem?  You need to get the server to respond to that URL, or find a URL that the server does respond to (`/beta`?), and put the rest in the hash (`/beta#/product/tab-5`), updating the anchors in your page if needed..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the question, but I believe it is no harder then saying:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.foo.com/alpha/product/#tab-5";
```

If that get's you to a 404 page, there is an issue on the server side, but that has nothing to do with the javascript 'redirect'